# Specify an input type name?

Tags: html, css, forms, input

I'm making a contact form. Now obviously I'll want the message box bigger than the Email and Subject input boxes. So obviously I can't just type in my input in css because it'll change all boxes. I thought specifying the message box would go something like this

```
input [type="text" name="message"] {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}
```

That obviously didn't work... So what am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div id="contactContent">
 <form>
 <label>Email:</label><input type="text" name="email" />
 <br>
 <label>Subject:</label><input type="text" name="subject" />
 <br>
 <label>Message:</label><input type="text" name="message" />
 </form>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#contactContent { 
    margin-top: 50px; 
    margin-left: 350px;
}
input { 
    border: none; 
    background-color: #CCCCCC; 
    margin-left: 20px; 
    margin-bottom: 5px; 
    padding-right: 250px;
    padding-top: 13px;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
}
label {
    display:inline-block;
    width:100px;
    font-family:maven;
    color: #FF6464;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: right;
}
input [type="text" name="message"] {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}
```

Comment: You can add a css class to the single element you want to modify. But, why don't you just use a textarea?

Comment: BTW, there is an `<input type="email" />`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your selector is incorrect, the correct way to apply a style to the element via both its type and name would be:

```
input[type="text"][name="message"] {
    padding-bottom: 500px;
}
```

Although you'd be better off using a class or id to target the element unless you have a good reason for doing it like that.

Comment: What's so bad using like this?

Comment: It's not as efficient as using a class or id. The difference isn't much here but if you had hundreds or thousands of rules like that you would end up with a needlessly larger file.

Answer (score 2):

The better option for a message box is the `<textarea>` element:

```
<label for="message">Message:</label>
<textarea id="message" name="message"></textarea>
```

Then styles for that don't compete with the input styles.

Anyhow, if for some reason you do just want a one line input, another styling hook would be a unique class or id.